# Adjectival form of the word "quota"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, derivational-morphology

If something is affected by a "reservation", you could consider it as "reserved", similarly if something is affected by a "lock", it is considered "locked".

How would you address something which is affected by a quota?

Comment: Can you provide a sentence in which you would want to use such a word?

Comment: There are examples online of the rare compound _quota-restricted_.

Comment: As a salesman, I can tell you I'm *quota-carrying*. Or, more colorfully, *I carry a bag*, unlike those management guys up in their ivory tower (note to management reading this: this is just an illustration of an English idiom, you know I love you guys ;).

Answer (score 1):

Since ***quota*** has only a noun form, I guess we need to go with a [synonym](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/quota) for the adjective form.
See if the adjective form of ***ration*** works:

> [rationed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rationed) - Adj.  1.  rationed - distributed equitably in limited
>   individual portions